# How to launch an application with admin rights

Tags: c#

I want to launch an application with admin rights. If it runs with limited user, a popup will appear (same as "Run as" context menu) so that user will input an Administrator account (user & pass), & switch my application rights to this user. Because my application will need permissions to operate.

I want to implement this feature in XP, & Vista.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be solved with the Impersonator class:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx

or this ImpersonateUser function:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx

some other options are to execute `RunAs /user:administrator "program"`

or add this to your original app's .manifest file (so privs are requested once at the start)

```
<requestedPrivileges>
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

Comment: Actually it was Windows XP that added support for application manifests. Its true though that the requestedPrivelages node was only supported from Windows Vista and later.